# Updating hover windows with new content

Tags: hover, vscode-extensions

When using vscode, and you hover on a keyword, a hover window appears with the definition of that keyword.
What I want to do, is to click on some words in the definition the hover window, in order to see the definition of that other keyword (like hypertext basically).
I've done most of the work, but I don't know how to change the content of the hover window.

Basically, here is my code:

```js
function log(message: string): void {
  vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`[StatefulHoverProvider] ${message}`);
}

class StatefulHoverProvider implements vscode.HoverProvider {

  private currentKeyword: string | null = null;
  private context: vscode.ExtensionContext;

  constructor(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    this.currentKeyword = null;
    this.context = context;
  }

  setCurrentKeyword(keyword: string) {
    this.currentKeyword = keyword;
  }

  async provideHover(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken): Promise<vscode.Hover | undefined> {
    if (this.currentKeyword && keywordDefinitions[this.currentKeyword]) {
      const relativePathToFile = keywordDefinitions[this.currentKeyword].definitionFile;
      try {
        const definition = await readDefinitionFile(this.context, relativePathToFile);
        const markdownContent = new vscode.MarkdownString();
        markdownContent.isTrusted=true;
        markdownContent.supportHtml=true;
        markdownContent.appendMarkdown(definition);
        this.currentKeyword=null;
        return new vscode.Hover(markdownContent);
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
          log(`Error reading definition file: ${err.message}`);
        } else {
          log('Error reading definition file');
        }
      }
    } else {
      const range = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position);
      const word = document.getText(range);
      if (keywordDefinitions[word]) {
        const relativePathToFile = keywordDefinitions[word].definitionFile;
        try {
          const definition = await readDefinitionFile(this.context, relativePathToFile);
          const markdownContent = new vscode.MarkdownString();
          markdownContent.isTrusted=true;
          markdownContent.supportHtml=true;
          markdownContent.appendMarkdown(definition);
          return new vscode.Hover(markdownContent);
        } catch (err) {
          if (err instanceof Error) {
            log(`Error reading definition file: ${err.message}`);
          } else {
            log('Error reading definition file');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


function showKeywordDefinition(keyword: string) {
  if (keywordDefinitions[keyword]) {
    log("Found the work in the hover: ".concat(keyword));
    hoverProvider.setCurrentKeyword(keyword);
    log("Set the keyword in the hover correctly");
    // Trigger an update for the hover provider
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.showHover');
  } else {
    vscode.window.showErrorMessage(`Keyword "${keyword}" not found.`);
  }
}


export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  const showDefinitionCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.showKeywordDefinition', showKeywordDefinition);
  context.subscriptions.push(showDefinitionCommand);
}
```

everything works as expected, but when the extension tries to call:

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.showHover');
```

it doesn't work at all.
Do you have an idea, on how to make it work, so the hover definition is updated with the new definition of the clicked keyword?

Thank you in advance for your help!